# John D. Anderson Fundamentals of Aerodynamics Example 2.2

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, flow, aerodynamics

I'm having trouble understanding the derivation of the integral for Coefficient of Friction in Example 2.2 of John Anderson's Fundamentals of Aerodynamics 5e.  I'm not sure how the author cancels $$ V_\infty^2c $$ and places the freestream velocity inside the integral.
$$ \frac{u_2}{V_\infty}(\frac{u_1}{V_\infty}-\frac{u_2}{V_\infty}) $$
Equations below:

> **Solution**
> From Equation $(2.84)$ $$C_f=\frac{D'}{q_{\infty} c}=\frac{\rho_{\infty}}{\frac{1}{2}\rho_{\infty} V^2_{\infty}c}\int_0^{\delta}u_2(u_1-u_2)dy$$ where the integral is evaluated at the trailing edge of the plate. Hence, $$C_f=1\int_0^{\delta/2}\frac{u_2}{V_{\infty}}\left(\frac{u_1}{V_{\infty}}-\frac{u_2}{V_{\infty}}\right)d\left(\frac yc\right)$$

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). I have edited your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple. Since $\dfrac{1}{V_\infty^2c}$ is a constant, it can be inserted into the integral. Thus, one $\dfrac{1}{V_\infty}$ goes into the factor
$$\frac{u_2}{V_\infty},$$
the other $\dfrac{1}{V_\infty}$ goes into the factor
$$\left(\frac{u_1}{V_\infty} - \frac{u_2}{V_\infty}\right),$$
and the $\dfrac{1}{c}$ goes into
$$d\left(\frac{y}{c}\right).$$
Notice that the upper limit of the integral becomes $\delta/c$ and not $\delta/2$.

Comment: Of course!  Brilliant, thank you so much! @Tofi

Comment: @Tom Glad to help 